# Safe to change TMPDIR?

Tags: terminal, macos, environment-variables

I recently installed Open MPI, and it's complaining

```
PMIx has detected a temporary directory name that results
in a path that is too long for the Unix domain socket:
Temp dir: /var/folders/**/*****************************/T/openmpi-sessions-501@host*******************************/*****
```

[This question](https://github.com/LLNL/spack/issues/3567) suggests setting `TMPDIR` to `/tmp`. Is that safe? Will it mess up other programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be [security flaws that result from the careless use of `/tmp`](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2008-0525); malicious local users may be able to delete arbitrary files or possibly even run arbitrary code under your user account, depending on how bad the `/tmp` flaw is. A solution that remains within the `char sun_path[104]` [limit on unix domain sockets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367008/why-is-socket-path-length-limited-to-a-hundred-chars/367012) (see `/usr/include/sys/un.h` for the definition) is to create a temporary directory and use that for MPI:

```
$ mktemp -d /tmp/mpi-XXXXXXXX
/tmp/mpi-zUN9SQo6
```

which leaves 86 characters for the socket file to use (104 minus one for the trailing `NUL` minus 17).

Depending on where and when you set `TMPDIR` other programs could easily be messed up, notably `tmux` or `screen` that then may not then be able to locate their control socket. If possible, scope the custom `TMPDIR` setting as close to the MPI calls as possible, e.g. with a shell function or alias along the lines of

```
alias mpi4py='TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/mpi-XXXXXXXX) mpi4py'
```

This would create a unique temporary directory for each invocation; the directories in `/tmp` are pruned automatically. If a shared or more persistent directory is needed `/var/tmp` is typically more suitable

```
$ mkdir /var/tmp/mympi
```

**and be sure to confirm the directory did not already exist** in the event a far too clever local attacker has already created that directory (unlikely, but this is why `mktemp -d` was created). Then, in your shell profile the alias might look something like

```
alias mpi4py='TMPDIR=/var/tmp/mympi mpi4py'
```

This form is again more suitable if there is shared state necessary between different MPI command invocations.

Comment: `/private/tmp` gets pruned regularly. If I just want one fixed tmp location for a specific application I would probably just create `/tmp/APPNAME_temp` and use this.

Comment: Just for the sake of generalization: The method is to create a *new* temporary tempdir, use that for mpi, and then when mpi is done `TMPDIR` is back to the old value? So if I want to use `mpi4py` I can change `TMPDIR`, do whatever, and then just close that terminal?

Comment: And should your command at the end be `alias yourmpicommand='TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/mpi-XXXXXXXX) yourmpicommand'` like above? Or is that something different?

Comment: You would set an appropriate `alias` in your shell configuration; the terminal would not need to be closed as the custom environment would only apply to the command with the alias. Learning the basics of e.g. `bash` may be beneficial if this all seems mysterious.

Comment: But if I alias `mpiexec`, for example, then a new `TMPDIR` would be set every time I run `mpiexec`. That doesn't seem like what I want to do. (Or is it?)

Comment: I showed how to either use a single unique tmp directory or how to make a new one each run. I am not familiar enough with MPI to know which if either is more suitable.